# How to get the email address of the the user currently authenticated user? currently returning null

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I would like to see the email and the profile name of the user currently logged in and authenticated in my WebApp.

The backend of my app is in PHP and I am currently using the offical google API PHP client library and gets access to the Google Drive account of the user.

In order to get the name i have been trying to go though the userinfo endpoint.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
echo(serialize($googleOAuth->userinfo->get()->name) . '   ');
```

However this is not giving me the users email address its currently returning empty.

These are the authorization scopes i have request of the user:

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE);
```

How do I get the email?

**EDIT**

I added the scopes:

```
$client->addScope('email');
$client->addScope('profile');
```

And then it works with the Google_Service_Oauth2 Object.

Answer (score 1):

I dont recommend using the userinfo endpoint for this the data returned is not always returned.  you should go though the people api [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

```
$service = new Google_Service_People($client);
$response = $service->people->get("people/me");
```

Comment: I added inputFields parameters array('requestMask.includeField' => 'person.names,person.emailAddresses'). But I also get only the name and not the mail